# Windows installer from angular app

Tags: angularjs, windows, electron

I'm reading some information to become my angular app as a desktop application. I started to read some information about electron.

http://electron.atom.io/

Here in the main page I read that I can create a windows installer but after a deeper research I found

https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-windows-installer

I don't know which is the main difference or finally in essence is the same library or process? Sorry if it's duplicated but I searched and didn't find anything and I'm a bit lost.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind is that you can deliver you application bundled with electron, so that you don't need a web server/application server and your application runs fully locally.

the supported platform are defined here:
http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.5/tutorial/supported-platforms/

And you need the specific binary for the specific platform that you want to use. (jvm like)

I hope it helps.

Comment: I suppose that this is about Electron. So what it's the reason of the package electron-windows-installer

Comment: that because you have a version for windows and a version for mac. Is like the java jvm you need the native system version to run java bitecode.